# Chart parameters for chart.CumReturns (Perf. Analytics)

Tags: r, performanceanalytics

I am trying to change some parameters in the above mentioned chart. Concretely, I want to do the following:

1. making the axis labels and ylab smaller
2. Removing the title and free up the space for the chart
3. align the ylabels horizontally instead of vertically

My code looks as follows

```
opar <- par(oma = c(0.1,0.2,0,0.1))
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0),plt=c(0,0.1,0,0.1),mgp=c(3,0.5,0),pin=c(1,1),fin=c(0.2,0.2),
  las=1,mex=0.5,cex.main=0.6,cex.lab=0.3,cex.axis=0.3)
chart.CumReturns(returns_ts,geometric=TRUE,wealth.index=TRUE,main="",xlab="",col=hblue,cex.axis=0.8,cex.lab=0.6,las=1)
par(xpd=NA)
legend(legend=paste(paste(c("Performance indexiert"),strats[i])),cex=0.7, col=hblue,lty=1, lwd=2, bty="n", 
text.col="black", ncol=1, "bottom", inset = c(0.0, -.20))
text_note=c(paste("Quelle: Bloomberg,", "letzter Datenpunkt:", last(data$date)))
mtext(text_note ,cex=0.4,col=hgrey,side = 1, line = 4, outer = FALSE,padj=0,adj=1)                                                                                                                                      #ensures that the text is shown at the                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
grid.raster(pic,x=c(0.05),y=c(0.02),width=0.05,height=0.03)
```

However, nothing is happening, ie, none of the parameters is changed. I also tried with

```
main=NULL
```

Then, the name of the time series shows up.

Can you help me out?

Regards
Andreas

Answer (score 0):

Revision 3241 repairs a bug in the underlying `chart.TimeSeries` function; it had been passing `cex.main` and `cex.lab` incorrectly into the `title` function.  Thanks for pointing that out.  The development code is on r-forge if you want to load it from there.

More generally, these charts don't use `par` very well.  Specifically, altering the chart attributes using `par()` directly won't work.  I realize that isn't quite right and I've been meaning to fix it for a couple of years, but there's always something else to do...

So the best way to pass in the attributes you want is directly through the function.  If you want to get rid of the title, use `main=""`.  Passing `las` was also be a recent fix, so it works for me.  Here's a reproducible example:

```
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
data(managers)
par(mar=c(1,4,4,2)) # c(bottom, left, top, right)
chart.CumReturns(managers[,1:3],geometric=TRUE,wealth.index=TRUE,main="",xlab="",col=bluefocus,cex.axis=0.8,cex.lab=0.6,las=1)
par(xpd=NA)
legend(legend=paste(paste(c("Performance indexiert"),"1")),cex=0.7, col=bluefocus,lty=1, lwd=2, bty="n", 
text.col="black", ncol=1, "bottom", inset = c(0.0, -.20))
text_note=c(paste("Quelle: Bloomberg,", "letzter Datenpunkt:", "last(data$date)"))
mtext(text_note ,cex=0.4,col="grey",side = 1, line = 4, outer = FALSE,padj=0,adj=1)
```

With the revisions, that should work the way you expect.  Sorry for the trouble, and let me know if you see anything else amiss.

pcc

Comment: Thanks for this. How would I best make use of your fix? Create a new function or override your original function? How would that work?         Another issue I have is that it seems not possible to chart multiple series in the bar chart in PerformanceSummary charts. It would be great if that was available. Andreas